# Android Studio paste issue

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Whenever I try to paste some lines of code into a file in Android Studio it acts like this:

1. Copied lines overwrite existing lines below caret position.
2. It pastes several times for a single command (I copy 7 lines and press Ctrl+V just once and it gives me 49 lines)

I don't know if this is some weird coding feature that I'm unaware of.

How can I turn this behavior off and make it work the ordinary way?

**Update**
it's not a keyboard issue. No problem in Visual Studio!

Comment: You sure it's not your keyboard? #1 seems like you have "insert" key active on your keyboard. #2 could a malfunctioning key. Have you tested on other editors?

Comment: I turned off insert and it's working like charm. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I don't even know if I should put this as an answer haha. Others have already said the same.

Comment: Oh! it's getting funnier! 
I don't think it was the insert key.

Comment: When I select the lines by mouse it works, when I use the keyboard (shift + down arrow) it goes crazy again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case someone else should face a similar issue in the future, mine was fixed after I marked and then unmarked Column Selection Mode (Alt+Shift+Insert).

Still strange but it resolved the issue!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue I fix by clear android studio cache

File ---> Invalidate Caches/Restart

[image]

Another solution

instead using ctrl + v Use ctrl + Alt + Shift + V

Answer (score 0):

#### Probable Reasons:

1. You are copying from somewhere where lines are hiding inside compact brackets
2. Your keys/keyboard is gone might generating 7 times same signal for a command (7*7 = 49)

Please check

Answer (score 0):

In android studio 2.2 or above hold Control key then drag the layout or widget to duplicate

Answer (score -2):

Press the 'insert' button on your keyboard (labeled "ins")

Comment: I made sure insert is off. the only way it works is when I put the caret in the beginning of the first line, hold shift and click after the last line to make the selecting. Using Shift+Arrow keys leads to the above mentioned issues, so does dragging mouse to select.